# Unreachable Statement in switch

Tags: java, switch-statement, break

So I have a switch statement that will switch on each string in an array. When it encounters an operator, it will add that to an ArrayList. However, for some reason, when I compile the code it says that certain statements are "unreachable". I've marked which statements are the offending ones in my code below with "//".

Thanks in advance!

Code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class a3
{

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
{
    ArrayList<Token> tokens = new ArrayList<Token>();
    String[] readTokens;
    Stack<Operator> postStack = new Stack<Operator>();

    String filename = "input.infix";
    String DELIM = " ";

    File in = new File(filename);
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(in);

    while (sc.hasNextLine())
    {
        readTokens = sc.nextLine().split(DELIM);

        for (String s : readTokens)
        {
            switch(s)
            {
                case "(": 
                    tokens.add(new Operator(opType.LPAR));
                    break;

                case ")": 
                    tokens.add(new Operator(opType.RPAR));
                    break; //unreachable

                case "*": 
                    tokens.add(new Operator(opType.MULT));
                    break; //unreachable 

                case "/": 
                    tokens.add(new Operator(opType.DIV));
                    break; //unreachable 

                case "%": 
                    tokens.add(new Operator(opType.MOD));
                    break; //unreachable 

                case "+": 
                    tokens.add(new Operator(opType.ADD));
                    break; //unreachable 

                case "-": 
                    tokens.add(new Operator(opType.SUB));
                    break; //unreachable 

                //Assuming the expression are valid (according to the
                //assignment notes, anything other than operators are
                //operands.
                //
                //NOTE: Even though spaces exist, they will not be
                //interpreted as they are the delim

                default: 
                    tokens.add(new Operand(Integer.parseInt(s)));
                    break; //unreachable 
            }
        }

    String postfix = infix2postfix(tokens);
    int finalResult = evalPostfix(postfix);

    System.out.println(postfix + " = " + finalResult);
    }
}   

public static String infix2postfix(ArrayList<Token> al)
{
    return "";
}

public static int evalPostfix(String post)
{
    return 0;
}

}
```

Comment: Are you on Java 7? Otherwise you can't do a switch on Strings. And could you make it more clear which cases are unreachable?

Comment: are you compile in **java 7**

Comment: did you mean to comment out the break statements? if the are the offenders put `//unreachable` in case statement

Comment: Do you mean you *don't* have breaks there or the *breaks are unreachable*? By commenting out the breaks themselves it's unclear.

Comment: Yes I am on Java 7 (1.7.0_45). The offending lines should be shown with //unreachable

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce this issue. I mocked `Operand`, `Operator`, `Token` and `opType` and everything compiles just fine.

Comment: Maybe try cleaning your project. I tried your code, and it works fine.

Comment: Are you compiling on Java 7 or only running with Java 7?

Comment: Actually, I think it's a project-cleaning issue as well.  If only the first case works, it's probably a version lingering around that only has the first case, which you may have run before implementing the remaining cases of the switch statement.  Just a thought.

Answer (score 3):

I added the missing class/interface/enum declarations to your code and cannot reproduce the error.  The problem is clearly in code you haven't posted.

Here's what compiles fine for me:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Test
{

    public static interface Token
    {
    }

    public static class Operator implements Token
    {
        public Operator(opType type)
        {
        }
    }

    public static enum opType
    {
        LPAR, RPAR, MULT, DIV, MOD, ADD, SUB
    }

    public static class Operand implements Token
    {
        public Operand(int val)
        {
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException
    {
        ArrayList<Token> tokens = new ArrayList<Token>();
        String[] readTokens;
        Stack<Operator> postStack = new Stack<Operator>();

        String filename = "input.infix";
        String DELIM = " ";

        File in = new File(filename);
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(in);

        while (sc.hasNextLine())
        {
            readTokens = sc.nextLine().split(DELIM);

            for (String s : readTokens)
            {
                switch (s)
                {
                    case "(":
                        tokens.add(new Operator(opType.LPAR));
                        break;

                    case ")":
                        tokens.add(new Operator(opType.RPAR));
                        break;

                    case "*":
                        tokens.add(new Operator(opType.MULT));
                        break;

                    case "/":
                        tokens.add(new Operator(opType.DIV));
                        break;

                    case "%":
                        tokens.add(new Operator(opType.MOD));
                        break;

                    case "+":
                        tokens.add(new Operator(opType.ADD));
                        break;

                    case "-":
                        tokens.add(new Operator(opType.SUB));
                        break;

                        // Assuming the expression are valid (according to the
                        // assignment notes, anything other than operators are
                        // operands.
                        //
                        // NOTE: Even though spaces exist, they will not be
                        // interpreted as they are the delim

                    default:
                        tokens.add(new Operand(Integer.parseInt(s)));
                        break;
                }
            }

            String postfix = infix2postfix(tokens);
            int finalResult = evalPostfix(postfix);

            System.out.println(postfix + " = " + finalResult);

        }
    }

    public static String infix2postfix(ArrayList<Token> al)
    {

        return "";
    }

    public static int evalPostfix(String post)
    {

        return 0;
    }

}
```

Comment: Same here, and I compiled successfully with Java SE 1.7.  All breaks work fine.  Check your code again, SlashTag.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is completely fine as suggested buy others.
It is okay to put a `break` inside a statement a `swhich` lock. But the break should be at the last statement, you probably have forgotten in some of the case statements.